# Would it be possible to get list of index of components BY SELECTION ORDER in Edit Mode?

Tags: python, vertices, faces, sverchok

[image: diagram of sorting order]

Not sure if Blender has a built in mechanism that "knows" the order the user selects Objects in 3D view or Components by Index.

I wanted to achieve this using Python for later usage incorporated into node in Sverchok or Animation Nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bmesh records (or provides access to) the [selection history](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.select_history) of a mesh.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object

if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
elif obj.mode == 'OBJECT':
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(obj.data)

for i in bm.select_history:
    print(type(i),i.index)
```

Notice the use of `type()` as the history list can contain verts, edges and faces at the same time and in any order.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Works really well when I select the component one by one using RMB click. But when I use C and draw select, it does not quite work. Is there a work around?

Comment: Seems it only works with manual selection, any other selection method fails to add to the history, though deselecting always removes items. I would consider that a bug.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Based on Python from @sambler above I tested and use Sverchok nodes to re-order the index of Polygon Face.

Comment: Answers are for answers to the original question only, not to post updates on how well another answer worked.