# Merge 2 vertices at LAST and at CURSOR in Python

Tags: python, mesh, vertices

I need to merge 2 vertices into one with bpy.ops.mesh.merge(type='LAST').
I select 2 vertices, however there is no saved select order to them so I can't use merge with parameter 'LAST'.

```
import bpy, bmesh

obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
objData = obj.data
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
meshData = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(objData)
vertices = meshData.verts
#select 2 testing vertices
vertices[0].select = True
vertices[1].select = True
bpy.ops.mesh.merge(type='LAST')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "LAST" not found in ('CENTER', 'CURSOR', 'COLLAPSE')
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

So instead I tried to snap the 3D cursor to the first selected vertex to be able to use merge with parameter 'CURSOR':

```
#select 2 testing vertices
vertices[0].select = True
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
vertices[1].select = True
bpy.ops.mesh.merge(type='CURSOR')
```

And I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I change context to View 3D (if only 'OBJECT', 'EDIT', 'SCULPT', 'VERTEX_PAINT', 'WEIGHT_PAINT', 'TEXTURE_PAINT' are available) or am I missing something? And how come I am able to manually do it on the object in EDIT mode?
2. Is there any way to edit the selection order of vertices so I can use merge with parameter 'LAST' as I originally intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by manipulating the mesh itself using the [Bmesh module](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html):

[Would it be possible to get list of index of components BY SELECTION ORDER in Edit Mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77824/would-it-be-possible-to-get-list-of-index-of-components-by-selection-order-in-ed)

You can access the selection history and proceed with the `bmesh.ops` calls for merging vertices:

```
bmesh.ops.pointmerge(bm, verts, merge_co)
```

Or do it entirely manually by modifying the mesh data itself.

If you have any UV's or vertex colors, you will have to take care of them too.

Comment: `bm.select_history` seems to work only in manual selection, it doesn't store anything that was selected using `vertices[0].select = True`
--
`bmesh.ops.pointmerge(bm, verts, merge_co)` is working for me and does exactly what I want however it crashes, but after adding `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(objData)` it works just fine. 

Thank you very much